# Select one record using multiple group by and count

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0, lambda

I have a list of entities where the entity likes

***Offer***

```
Int OfferId
DateTime FromDate
DateTime ToDate
Bool Status
```

In the `List<Offer>`, it has duplicate `OfferId` as well
Eg.

```
Offer1 { Id=1, From=01/01/2011, To=31/01/2011, Status=true }
Offer2 { Id=1, From=01/02/2011, To=28/02/2011, Status=false}
Offer2 { Id=2, From=01/02/2011, To=28/02/2011, Status=false}
Offer3 { Id=3, From=01/01/2011, To=31/01/2011, Status=true }
Offer4 { Id=4, From=01/01/2011, To=31/01/2011, Status=true }
Offer5 { Id=1, From=01/03/2011, To=31/03/2011, Status=false}
```

What I am trying to do is **select a list of offers** related to one `offerId` which has the oldest and most frequent `startdate`.
In this case it is the once with `offerId=1`. Because it has the startdate `01/01/2011` which is oldest and the most frequent.
I am not sure how to put the all conditions in a one command.

I grouped the records based on `offerId`, but I'm not sure how to continue

```
var list = OfferList.GroupBy(a => a.offerId).Select(g => g.Select(s => s));
```

**Update**

Seems like bit confusion. I am trying to select list or records which satisfy the conditions. 
In this case answer should be

```
Offer1 { Id=1, From=01/01/2011, To=31/01/2011, Status=true }
Offer2 { Id=1, From=01/02/2011, To=28/02/2011, Status=false}
Offer5 { Id=1, From=01/03/2011, To=31/03/2011, Status=false}
```

Because, this offerid which is ***1*** has the oldest fromdate which is ***01/01/2011*** and it also has the most frequent fromdate which is ***01/01/2011***. (01/01/2011 is appear 3 times as the fromdate in main list )

Comment: Which is takes priority oldest or most frequent?

Comment: @Hogan: Need to check the oldest first and from oldest set,the most frequent date

Comment: What happens if the oldest date is not the most frequent start date?

Comment: So are you passing in the oldest start date. From the original and now updated question it seems like this start date is in a separate list structure. Can you show that list as well? Do you need to do a merge on these two lists when comparing? From the data presented, StartDate is just a magic number that is not in the `Offer` object.

Comment: @pstrjds:ops sorry, its the from date not start date. Updated !!!

Comment: @huMptyduMpty - I strongly recommend you download LinqPad for these kind of problems -- you can use my example from my answer to see how powerful and useful this free tool is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go and here is the LinqPad test: https://gist.github.com/3207484

```
var r = (OfferList.GroupBy(offer => offer.id)
             .Select(group =>
                 new { offerid = group.Key,
                       offers = group.OrderBy(o => o.fromDt),
                       count = group.Count() })
             .OrderBy(g => g.offers.First().fromDt) // list with the oldest
             .ThenByDescending(g => g.count)).Dump()  // then by most
        .First().offers.First();
```

Comment: @huMptyduMpty - ok it does that now -- just had to take out the last `First()`

Comment: @huMptyduMpty just a remark : if the offers with id 1 had the oldest date, but not the most frequent one, you will retrieve results. Is it desired ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus - yeah, see the comments on the OQ.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: The sample list I given in the list, 01/01/2011 is the most frequent start date !!! I didn't get the issue you talking about

Comment: @huMptyduMpty this was just a question ;) Thought your sample was... just a sample, and that different cases could happen !

Answer (score 1):

```
var q = from t in offerList
        group t by new { t.Id } into grp
        select new
        {
           grp.Key.Id,
           MinDate = grp.Min(t => t.From)
        };
var re = q.ToList().OrderBy(p=>p.MinDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

Not tested though

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this will return records with multiple offerid. I just need record related to one offer id which satisfy the conditions I mentioned in the question. Also is this checking for the most occurred fromdate??